# Geometric proof of $\sin(\theta)' = \cos(\theta)$ using infinitesimals

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, infinitesimals

In his book *Visual Complex Analysis*, Tristran Needham uses Newton's method of infinitesimals to derive the derivative $\tan(\theta)' = 1 + \tan^2(\theta)$ by using the following picture (where $T = \tan(\theta)$):
[image]

If $d\theta$ "goes to" zero, the black triangle becomes similar to the shaded triangle which yields $\frac{dT}{L d\theta} = \frac{L}{1} \Rightarrow \frac{dT}{d\theta} = L^2 = 1 + T^2$.

If I try to apply the same logic to $\sin(\theta)$ I don't get the correct result. My thinking: use the unit hypothenuse instead of the unit base. Then $L \rightarrow 1$, $1 \rightarrow C = \cos(\theta)$, $T \rightarrow S = \sin(\theta)$, $dT \rightarrow dS$ and $L \cdot d\theta \rightarrow d\theta$. But this gives the wrong result $\frac{dS}{d\theta} = \frac{1}{C}$.

Where's my error here? Please don't simply respond by objecting that the method is not rigorous.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show us the picture you are using?

Comment: @EthanBolker: Are you asking for a picture where the new quantities are visible or is the original tangent picture which I included in the post not visible to you?

Comment: I can see the image in the question. The answer from @DougM shows the one you should be using.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I was using the same, just with different labels. I see now that I wrongly extended the $S$ side. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the wrong picture for $\sin\theta.$

The equivalent picture would be something like...
[image]

Comment: Perfect, now I see my error. Thanks!